# Woocommerce round total price 0.05

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I setup a woocommerce shop for test purpose and tried to round the total price to 0.05 because we do this here in Switzerland ;)

But i hadn't any success and searched everywhere.

My code at the moment looks something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_subtotal', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'round_subtotal', 10, 3);


function round_subtotal( $cart_subtotal, $compound, $instance ) {
    $origValue = $cart_subtotal;
    preg_match( '/\d+\.\d+/', $origValue, $floatValue);
    $roundedValue = number_format( round_price_product( $floatValue[0] ), 2 );
    $returnValue = str_replace( $floatValue, $roundedValue, $origValue );
    return $returnValue;
}

function round_price_product( $price ){
    return round( $price * 2, 1 ) / 2;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Chris